# Is defining set equality using $\notin$ correct?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Two sets $A$ and $B$ are defined to be equal if $\forall x \in A,x\in B$ and vice-versa

I was thinking that it would be practical to define set equality using $\notin$, and that is:

Two sets $A$ and $B$ are defined to be equal if $\forall x \notin A,x\notin B$ and vice-versa

The reason I found this to be practical is that it is the easiest way to prove that we have only one empty set $\emptyset$, however, I do acknowledge that the definition would be impractical when it comes to proving two non-empty sets are equal but is it logically correct? I am new to set-theory and I am afraid I might be missing something so I am posting to make sure my logic isn't flawed.

Comment: This is really not a set theory question but a logic question. The sentences $p\implies q$ and $\lnot q\implies\lnot p$ are equivalent (contraposition, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition ). It follows that the sentences $p\iff q$ and $\lnot p\iff\lnot q$ are equivalent. It follows that $x\in A\iff x\in B$ and $x\not\in a\iff x\not\in B$ are equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two sets $A,B$ are equal means

$\forall x[x\in A\Longleftrightarrow x\in B]$.

This equivalently means that

$\forall x[x\not\in A\Longleftrightarrow x\not\in B]$.